# How can you check if a polynomial is invertible with NTL?

Tags: c++, ntl

I've searched for hours and have not found an answer. I am working with polynomials modulo another polynomial (so `ZZ_pE` objects). When I use the method `inv(ZZ_pE poly)`, the result is either the inverse (if it exists), or the following error message:

```
ZZ_p: division by non-invertible element
Abort trap: 6
```

I tried using a try/catch:

```
    while(1)
    {
    random(f);
    f = 2*f + 1;    
        try{
            inv(fi, f);
            break;
        }
        catch(...) {
            // f not invertible
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
```

but the error message still stops the program. As far as I know there is no `isInvertible` or similar method. How can I check if a polynomial is invertible?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  It is a maths question.

Comment: @Peter Not if the software library being used provides a way to do it.

Comment: @aschepler - the OP mentioned there is no such method in NTL.   That means he's seeking an algorithm.   That makes it a math question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if a polynomial is invertible in `ZZ_pE` highly depends on your choice of `p` and polynomial you use for the modulo. In NTL `p` don't have to be prime, so `ZZ_p` does not need to be a field and the polynomial does not need to be irreducable, so `ZZ_pE` can be anything.

Your solution don't work because NTL throws errors instead of exceptions by default. But you can change this if you compile NTL using the option `NTL_EXCEPTIONS=on`.
See http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-unix.html for more details.